# 'npm install -D sass' What does it mean?

Tags: npm, next.js, sass

I'm going to use sass with Next.js.
So I explored documents then I found the solution.
And I saw `npm install -D sass`.
I already knew that npm stands for node package manager.
But I can't know the meaning of `-D`
Could you explain the meaning of `-D`?

I'd like to know the meaning of `-D` in `npm install -D sass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-D` is a shortcut for `—-save-dev`

The --save-dev option tells **npm** to add the package to the **devDependencies** section of your `package.json` file, which is typically used to specify dependencies that are **only** needed during development, such as testing frameworks, build tools...